# Android and iPhone PNS details

Tags: c#, iphone, android, wcf-data-services

i am crating a wcf data service for sending notification to iPhone and Android devices. i am writing server side code to register the devices, i just want to know what all  information iPhone and Android send to server for registration process and what all things i need to store in my data base for sending notification to iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS PNS are really different, and will not send the same amount or structure of information to handle device registration, unregistration and message handling. You should start from the specific documentations from both those worlds and implement different services for each of them. These two worlds cannot be collapsed into one, I fear ...

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Service will not allow you to do push notifications to Android and iPhone. WCF Data Service (OData service = REST) offers only request response message exchange pattern where client (Android and iPhone) must ask for data by sending a request.